# How to .unload() or .onbeforeunload() to dynamically created iframe

Tags: iframe, mouseleave

I need to show alert when window leave or refresh or entering new url in same tab. here i created iframe using jquery. with in that iframe i wrote unload event . but its not working.

```
document.getElementById("#ioi_widget_674").addEventListener("unload", function(){  //action here  alert("test"); });
```

i need to show alert in iframe when i leave window.